# Unable to change the property of localStorage on a click of button

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have + (plus one) button in my menu list UI and I have written a javascript code to store the details of the products chosen by the user in localStorage.
When I hit the "+" button, it increments the "quantity" key present in the localStorage, but when I hit it again, I get the error:-

```
Uncaught TypeError: locStore.forEach is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.addONe
```

I'm unable to figure out what's going wrong.

**MY DOUBT:** 
I want the localStorage's quantity key to be incremented every-time I hit the "+" button. But if you see in under Console Output, the quantity increases only once to "2" when I hit the "+" button. When I hit "+" button again, it shows the above error.

I've added the image here for showing the line number, so that you can verify with the console output

```
//for the + buttons present in the menu list - not for the cart increase
function addONe(event) {
  let button = event.target; //stores the button class like <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button-add">+</button>
  let shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement;
  //shopItem stores <div class="shop-item">title, image, details </div>
  let shopId = shopItem.getAttribute("id"); //get the ID of the shopItem

  let recParent = button.parentElement; //stores shop-item-details which is under "shop-item" in heirarchy
  let cinput = recParent.getElementsByClassName("shop-item-input")[0]; //will return the first <input class="shop-item-input">
  cinput.value++; //cinput.value stores the current quantity - typeof string
  var locStore = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("selectedProduct"));
  locStore.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.productID === shopId) {
      item.quantity = cinput.value;
      console.log(item.quantity);
      localStorage.setItem("selectedProduct", JSON.stringify(item));
    }
  });
```

**CONSOLE OUTPUT:** 
[image]

**locStore:** 
[image]

Comment: what is `locStore`, an array or something else?

Comment: What, exactly does `localStorage.getItem("selectedProduct")` return because you are parsing that into an object and attempting to call the `Array.forEach()` method on that object. If it does not return something that can be parsed into an Array, that would explain your error.

Comment: Looks like you have an object and not an array

Comment: Even if the content of `"selectedProduct"` was an array in the past, the `.forEach()` would overwrite it with an object: `localStorage.setItem("selectedProduct", JSON.stringify(item))`

Comment: @luk2302 Just edited the question with a screenshot of locStore structure. Please have a look.

Comment: _"but when I hit it again"_ - See my comment above

Comment: @BillalBegueradj I added the screenshot because it has line numbers. which can be seen in the console output as well.  I'll remove the code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Array.from(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("selectedProduct")));
```